# I removed /bin on my Mac, How can I restore it?

Tags: macos

I removed the `/bin` instead of `~/bin` :(

My laptop no longer boots up! It has no DVD or CD drive!

How can I restore the OS X?

It is MacBook Pro OS X 10.8, SSD 128GB.

Comment: I did edit the accepted answer on the linked question - if you delete /bin - some common tools like `cp` will be missing, but you do still have `tar` and can `cd /; tar -cvf - /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/bin | tar -xf -`